# c++ parsing string with format

Tags: c++, strip

i'm busy for a game for which i must parse a .txt file 
each row contains a format like this `[goblin;2;30x1;1-5;20;5]`

the values are as follows:

- name
- level
- attack (before the x the percentage of success, behind the x the amount of attacks in a single turn)
- damage (the minimum and maximum possible damage)
- defence (percentage a succesfull attack is still denied)
- hp

my current code is this:

```
    std::stringstream sstream(monsterLine);

    // Name is until the first comma.
    std::getline(sstream, monster.name, ';');

    // Then its spaces seperating the values.
    sstream >> monster.level;
    sstream >> monster.attackPoints;
    sstream >> monster.damagePoints;
    sstream >> monster.defensePoints;
    sstream >> monster.lifePoints;
```

this however only works if i format a string like `goblin;2 30x1 1-5 20 5`
how can i make it work with the above format?

Specific:
how can i check if the current line is placed within [...] and strip them.
how can i split the values by `;` instead of `(whitespace)`

Comment: Will there be any whitespace around the semicolon? If not then just read (and discard) those characters.

Comment: no, only whitespace that can be included is within the name of the monster.
how can i discard the character? i came across `erase(pos)` on the internet but that doesn't seem to exist for the output type of std::getline()

Comment: How about [ignoring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the character. Or as I said in my first comment, just ***read it*** then throw away the character (i.e. read into a dummy `char` variable and that's it).

Comment: _"// Name is until the first comma."_ That is not a comma.

Comment: _"// Then its spaces seperating the values."_ Not sure why you wrote this; as you told us yourself, that is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline` can be used for tokenization of a string.

```
if( (monsterLine.length() > 2) && 
    (monsterLine[0] == '[') && 
    (monsterLine[monsterLine.length() - 1] == ']') )
    {
        std::string szNewMonsterLine = monsterLine.substr(1, monsterLine.length() - 2);
        std::stringstream ss(szNewMonsterLine);

        if(getline(ss, monster.name, ';'))
        {   
            //some problem fetching data            
        }
        if(getline(ss, monster.level, ';'))
        {   
            //some problem fetching data            
        }
        if(getline(ss, monster.attackPoints, ';'))
        {   
            //some problem fetching data            
        }
        ...
        ...
        if(getline(ss, monster.lifePoints, ';'))
        {   
            //some problem fetching data
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue using `getline` with `;` as a delimiter.

The `>>` operator can't recognize `;`. It could work only with spaces.